# Probablity $nCr$ problem days of week $3$ chosen.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Straight from my daughter's math book :)

You work $3$ evenings. Your boss assigns you $3$ evenings at random from $7$. What's the probability of Friday being chosen.

We did this long hand (drew out all possibilities) at found $\dfrac{15}{35}$. The $35$ comes from combinations $\binom{7}{3}$ and we understand that.

How the heck do we get the $15$ possible "good" outcomes though to finish the problem? $5+4+3+2+1$ is how it worked out on paper, but not sure how that fits in with the above.

Ok, that's $\binom{6}{2}$, (love Pascal's triangle!) but still head scratching on why $6$ and $2$.

I got all the way through linear Algebra/Dif Eq, but never took a statistics course and I am now exposed :)

Comment: Can you please edit your post to use MathJax? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Love to - what numbers above need formulas?

Comment: The binomial coefficients (the choose functions). It's easier to read them as binomials. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the edits as well!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but here is an alternative solution: three of the seven days of the week have been designated as work days, while the other four are non-work days.  I pick a day of the week at random.  What is the probability that the day I pick is a work day?  The answer is $\dfrac{3}{7}=\dfrac{_3C_1}{_7C_1}$, which is the number of outcomes in which the selected day is a work day divided by the number of outcomes.  Since being a work day and being Friday are independent, the probability that Friday is a work day is also $\dfrac{3}{7}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get Friday, we assume it's there already in the set of days you work. That leaves $6$ days and we need $2$. So that's $\binom{6}{2} = 15$. The denominator is $35$, which you already got.

Comment: Ok, I know this is correct.  But, the "and we need 2" part of statement has lost me.

Comment: We have three days. Let's fix Friday as being in there. That means we need two more days we need to fill. Look at it as a set: ${Friday, _, _}$. You pick two days from six to stick in the blanks. Ordering doesn't matter, so we simply choose the days.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Excellent.  I'll be able to show and explain it to her in the morning.  The math book's "example" for the numerator had an example that only had "1" possible good answer and didn't show the secondary step.  Answer bonus for you in 5 minutes :)

Comment: Glad I could help! In my experience, Stats books aren't great at explaining counting problems. Combinatorics and Discrete texts are usually much better at it.

Comment: This is the last chapter of an Algebra book.  Lol.

Comment: Gotcha. I can understand why the explanation wasn't intuitive then.